# How to setup Angular and Electron project to debug in visual studio code

Tags: angular, electron

I am creating a proof-of-concept Angular+Electron app and I'm stuck at the Debug phase because the breakpoints at my components are not being set.

This is my ..vscode\launch.json
[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMP9J.png)

So far I checked there is a sourceMap = true set in angular.json as per others have suggested but still no luck.
[angular.json sourceMap set to true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaRvW.png)

The Main process is hitting Electron Main breakpoints either by debugging the [Electron: Main] or the [Electron: All] configurations
[Debugging Electron:Main hits the breakpoint at electron's main.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd5C9.png)

But the Renderer process does not hit breakpoints at Angular components.

**Scenario 1**
Run the application through Electron (nx build && electron .)
Attempt to debug using the [Electron: Renderer] configuration
I get an error:
"Cannot connect to the target at localhost:9223: Could not connect to debug target at http:localhost:9223: Could not find any debuggable target"

**Scenario 2**
Breakpoint at main.js that "delays" electron from fully loading the Angular app
Debug through the [Electron: All] configuration

With the above scenario: Breakpoints at main.js are hit and eventually I get the same "Canot connect to the target at localhost:9223"

**Scenario 3 - THE PROBLEM**
No breakpoint at main.js
Debug through the [Electron: All] configuration

The app loads, no error of any type, but the breakpoint at the Angular component is disabled
[Some of your breakpoints could not be set.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC6IB.png)

Final words: There are no soruce files at the loaded application so I cannot use DevTools either
[There are no source files at the loaded application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGiQI.png)